# Resetting EqualLogic PS6000XV iSCSI SAN Storage

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, network-attached-storage, dell-equallogic

K, so some background first. Just started working for this company as their sort of backup IT person. They have a bunch of projects that they never have to the time to work on, one such project is this EqualLogic PS6000XV iSCSI SAN Storage system. They acquired it from a company that moved out of the office space and didn't want to take all the server equipment with them. Unfortunately, said company left it as is, in other words passwords. My boss doesn't even know what they kept on it.

What I'm being asked to do is find a way to reset it so we can use is for storage. I'm pretty new to working with professional level servers, so what I'd like help with is,

1. Is there a simple way to reset this storage unit back to factory settings, or a way of resetting the password so that I can then erase everything currently on it.
2. Any and all recommended reading/research material for server newbies.

I found one article that looked promising, but I'm not sure I understand everything it's asking, so if this looks like what I need, maybe someone could better explain it to me?

https://www.vmguru.com/2010/03/resetting-the-grpadmin-password-on-a-dell-equallogic-san/

Any all help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Type **reset** in the CLI, enter the confirmation code and voila, the SAN will be reset at factory, and including data lost.

Answer (score 1):

The "reset" command can be used to perform a factory reset, but you must be logged in to run the command in the first place.

Typically resetting the password requires contacting support to get a response code needed to complete the process. This requires that you know the name of the company that the unit is registered to.

If you're not able to get help from support for any reason, the process documented in the article you linked should actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with JimNim, contact the support if you can't login to array as "grpadmin".

We used this article to reset our SANs few months ago:

http://www.vbloggen.dk/2015/08/28/how-to-wipe-and-reset-a-equallogic-san/

If it's impossible to contact the support for some reason, your article may work.